# Hidden mixed content in header.php wordpress

Tags: attributes, metadata, profile, mixed-content

I am crawling a WordPress client's website, it's having a mixed content error in the header.

However, when reading the header.php file, the external link is not there.

See the link here:
`<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">`

Did anyone experience this before?

I was reading a comment from Paul Tomblin who mentioned the importance of Meta-data profiles in WordPress, so this link might be important, I'd like to redirect it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also store external things in function.php and put it back in header.
Maybe you will find some entries there